# Package jar from Nexus using Assembly plugin

Tags: maven, maven-2, packaging

I am creating a tar file which contains a jar module, python files and other script files. The jar module needs some other jars which needs to be packaged inside tar.
I can place the related jars in the project and package it. But, I want to get the jars from Nexus.

I am using maven assembly plugin to create the tar.

Can you please suggest, how can I do it ?

Comment: Please show what you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `dependency:copy`:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html

Here you specify artifacts to be downloaded to a specific location.

Comment: Thanks JF Meier for the suggestion. It worked for me. I added configuration  <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive> to the plugin. But, still Junit jars are being fetched which I want to avoid. I tried adding <excludeArtifactIds>Junit</excludeArtifactIds>. But, it's not working. I will try to get rid of this problem.

Thanks